# Resultado Kmeans Python

Tags: python, funciones, algoritmos, diccionarios

Tengo que completar una función para calcular kmeans para distintos clusters. Se me proporciona parte del código que he ido completando, pero no consigo obtener kmeans_results

```
def run_KMeans(max_k, data):
max_k += 1
kmeans_results = dict()
for k in range(2 , max_k):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k
                    , init = 'k-means++'
                    , n_init = 10
                    , tol = 0.0001
                    , n_jobs = -1
                    , random_state = 1
                    , algorithm = 'full')

    kmeans_results [] =  # poner en un diccionario
    
return kmeans_results

kmeans_results = run_KMeans (12, tf_idf_df)
```

Comment: Comentar que se trata de un ejercicio para la universidad.

Comment: trata hacer `kmeans_results[len(kmeans_results)] = kmeans`

Comment: Vale, veo que así estaría guardando para cada k el modelo correspondiente. Muchas gracias @Christian